# Can GET channel list with mine=true return more than one channel?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am working on integrating our app with youtube and I need to get user's channel id after logging on. Is there any chance that, when using `/youtube/v3/channels?part=id&mine=true` endpoint, I will get more than 1 channel in result list?

I tried to create more channels using the same account, but it always resulted in creating new google account, and then having ALWAYS one channel in the result list. But maybe there is some kind of (legacy?) way to create more channels "attached" to the same google account.

Answer (score 0):

No, because when you authenticate, you have to choose to which channel you want to be authorized. And the token will be valid only for that channel.